# VirtualBox has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install virtualbox on ubuntu 20. I'm using the WSL2 on top of Windows 10. 
This is the error that I get. How can I fix this ?

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

thanks.